Realization of a constant simplicial anima
$\DeclareMathOperator\sAn{\mathit{sAn}}\DeclareMathOperator\An{\mathit{An}}$For the category of simpicial animas (simplicial $\infty$-groupoids if you like) $\sAn$, we have the evaluation functor $\mathrm{ev}_n:\sAn\rightarrow \An$ with a left adjoint $\operatorname{const}_n$ and the realization functor $\lvert\ \rvert:\sAn\rightarrow \An$ with a right adjoint being the Rezk nerve.
I wonder why $\Omega \lvert\operatorname{const}_1 X\rvert$ is $X$. This is used in the (4.1.27) in the Lecture notes: Lecture Notes on Algebraic K-Theory.
I can't even give a direct description for $\operatorname{const}_1X$. Is this something concerning the theory of Segal spaces…?

I don't think this is true as written, for example there are anima $X$ which are not loop spaces of anything (e.g. $X=S^2$). One can also directly see that $\mathrm{ev}_n$ is corepresented by $\Delta^n$, so I think the left adjoint must be given by $X\mapsto \Delta^n\otimes X$ (i.e. the object of $\mathrm{sAn}$ which takes $[m]$ to $\mathrm{Hom}_{\Delta}([m],[n])\otimes X$). This has realisation just equivalent to $X$.
I also don't see the claim you're asking about in the linked notes. In 4.1.27 they rather seem to argue that $\mathrm{const}_1\mathcal{C}$ realizes to $\mathcal{C}^\simeq$ (where they probably mean to first pass from simplicial categories to simplicial anima by discarding noninvertible morphisms levelwise, this then would fit with the above).

Thanks for your answer. In 4.1.27 $const_1(C)\rightarrow Q(C)$ only implies $|const_1(C^{\simeq})|\rightarrow |Q(C)^{\simeq}|$, but $K(C)=\Omega |Q(C)^{\simeq}|$(as in definition 4.1.24) so it seems that there may be some natural morphism $C^{\simeq}\rightarrow \Omega|const_1(C^{\simeq})|$. That's why I expected something about $\Omega|const_1(C^{\simeq})|$ to be told.

And I totally agree with you that this shouldn't be a equivalence.

AH, I think I know what's going on: When they write $\mathrm{const}_1(\mathcal{C})$, they don't mean your $\mathrm{const}1$, instead they mean the simplicial diagram left Kan extended from the functor $\Delta{\leq 1}\to \mathrm{Cat}$ taking $[0]\mapsto 0$ and $[1]\mapsto \mathcal{C}$. This should realize to the suspension of $\mathcal{C}^\simeq$, and a map $\Sigma\mathcal{C}^\simeq \to |Q(\mathcal{C})|$ corresponds to a map $\mathcal{C}^\simeq \to \Omega|Q(\mathcal{C})|$ by adjunction.
